# Java program that takes a file and separates line by line into two other files - Homework

Tags: java, try-catch

I need the program to read in a .txt file with multiple lines of random Strings and put every even line in one .txt file and every odd in another. It doesn't give me any errors, but the files are blank when I go check them. Thanks for any help :)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class SplitFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            // Open Scanner for file named args[0]
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            // Open a PrintWriter for file named args[1]
            PrintWriter file1 = new PrintWriter(new File(args[1]));
            // Open a PrintWriter for file named args[2]
            PrintWriter file2 = new PrintWriter(new File(args[2]));
            while (scan.hasNextLine())
            {
                // Read a line from scan
                // Write that line to file1
                file1.println(scan.nextLine() + ", ");

                if (scan.hasNextLine()) 
                {
                    // Read a line from scan
                    // Write that line to file2
                    file2.println(scan.nextLine() + ", ");
                }
            }
        }
        // Catch the IOException 
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: No Input Given");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should close the PrintWriter to flush the the output to the file. Once you are finished with the file operations, here is what you need to do:

```
file1.close();
file2.close();
```

**Note:** It will be better to declare `PrintWriter` objects outside the `try` block so that you can use the `finally` to close the writers.

Comment: The note part is also valid for the `Scanner`